# I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i, can't make calls but can receive them!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace

We have a phone at work that when ever the user makes an outgoing phone call it rings once then stops.
It was coming up with a message saying Call Forwarding is Active. So I disabled it to see if that was what was stopping it but that hasn't helped.
Has anyone had a similar issue? or know what to do?
He can receive calls on the phone just not make them.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Lewis Neville

Answer (score 0):

Might be signal or network problem. Sometimes it also happens to me. While I have strong signal but still not going calls. It says your call is forwarding but not making calls.

Comment: Since Disabling the Call forwarding settings that message hasn't come up. Now when I make an outgoing call, it rings once then just hangs up. And I can receive calls fine.